# Animated slides conversion to static PDF

Tags: pdf, animation, powerpoint, converters

For all of you, people who make ppt slides with animations like:

- Showing bullet points one by one
- Showing images one by one or zooming a plot
- Showing a border on an active element
- Internal navigation / menu / link to another slide
- Transitions between slides

Is there a tool that can convert the ppt to PDF and keep each animation in a separate slide, for example?

I know you can create animated slides with **[LaTeX Beamer](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/beamer)** that convert nicely to PDF, I have made some of those, but I also have some ppt files that I want to convert to PDF.

This is what I have tried so far:

- **[Slideshare](http://www.slideshare.net/)**, however not only it doesn't support animations, but internal navigation doesn't work, and the fonts are all messed up.
- **[PDFcreator](http://www.pdfforge.org/pdfcreator)**, the quality is quite superior in comparison, but it doesn't support the animations neither. As Slideshare, it will just put one image over the other. Also, it doesn't support transparency (for example, a text box with a semitransparent bg over an image)
- **LaTeX Beamer**, already mentioned, but I would prefer to avoid typing these ppts content and animations into LaTeX just so that the animations are displayed correctly in PDF.

I have searched SO and didn't find a satisfactory answer to deal with animations. What do you use?

Answer (score 19):

I found a small plugin that splits your powerpoint slides whenever they have animations. So if you have 3 animations on 1 slide he will generate 3 slides with each animation step by step. Then export it in PDF :-)

It worked for me on powerpoint 2010. I would recommend you do a backup file of presentation before splitting. And don't forget to uncheck the "Split on click-triggered animations".

http://www.dia.uniroma3.it/~rimondin/downloads.php

I also found this (but the first solution was free and worked so :-))
http://www.verypdf.com/wordpress/201306/how-to-create-a-pdf-from-powerpoint-with-animations-36850.html

Comment: FYI, I've not used it yet but [a blog post](http://blog.slidetalk.net/2016/01/how-to-split-powerpoint-animations-into.html) indicates that rimondin's PPspliT works with the PowerPoint 2016.

Comment: I've just used with PowerPoint 2016! Works wonders :) 
PS: You have to tell it to split first and then save. Do not overwrite your own ppt if you don't want to lose your animations.

Comment: Would you know of a way for this to work on google slides ? (i mean besides downloading as ppt and then splitting...)

Comment: One comment about any conversion that divides a slide with animations in to several slides - it will presumably change any slide counter on each slide, if a PDF were created from the generated PowerPoint file, the numbers on each slide would be different from the original presentation

Comment: @ClareMacrae the author thought of that. By default, ppsplit will preserve the original slide numbers

Answer (score 7):

This [blog post](http://neilmitchell.blogspot.co.uk/2007/11/powerpoint-pdf-part-2.html) provides a VBA macro script that will split every slide that has animations (e.g. images or bullet points that appear one by one) into multiple slides, and then you can save as PDF and voila!

Importantly, since it's a VBA script it **should work both for Windows and Mac**. I've only tried it on OSX (yosemite) with powerpoint 2011, and it worked pretty well. The only issue I had was that slides with animated bullet points (that appear one by one) were split into multiple slides but every slide contained all the bullet points, so I had to delete some manually. Still, for everything else it worked perfectly and it's a small price to pay compared to doing it all manually, especially image animations. Of course you may/may not encounter the same issue on Windows or other versions of PP. In any case, **for OSX it's the only working solution I've found so far.**

Instructions for adding VBA macros to powerpoint can be found [here](http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00033_How_do_I_use_VBA_code_in_PowerPoint.htm).

Hope it works for you too!

Comment: This does not work in Powerpoint for Mac 2008, as that version of PP does not support VBA.  The version previous and the version after *do*, but not the 2008 version.

Answer (score 4):

This [blog post](http://my2iu.blogspot.be/2010/04/powerpoint-2007-vba-macro-for-expanding.html) provides a VBA macro script that will split every slide that has animations into multiple slides, without keeping the original slides in front of the expanded slides (as is the case in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32302170/1731200)).

The problem that remains with this macro and the other macro, is that the content of a text block with multiple animations is always shown as a whole (e.g. if each sentence of the same text block has a separate animation, all sentences will always be shown together).

**VBA Code**:

```
Private AnimVisibilityTag As String

Sub ExpandAnimations()
AnimVisibilityTag = "AnimationExpandVisibility"

Dim pres As Presentation
Dim Slidenum As Integer

Set pres = ActivePresentation
Slidenum = 1
Do While Slidenum <= pres.Slides.Count
Dim s As Slide
Dim animationCount As Integer
Set s = pres.Slides.Item(Slidenum)

If s.TimeLine.MainSequence.Count > 0 Then
    Set s = pres.Slides.Item(Slidenum)
    PrepareSlideForAnimationExpansion s
    animationCount = expandAnimationsForSlide(pres, s)
Else
    animationCount = 1
End If
Slidenum = Slidenum + animationCount
Loop
End Sub

Private Sub PrepareSlideForAnimationExpansion(s As Slide)
' Set visibility tags on all shapes
For Each oShape In s.Shapes
oShape.Tags.Add AnimVisibilityTag, "true"
Next oShape

' Find initial visibility of each shape
For animIdx = s.TimeLine.MainSequence.Count To 1 Step -1
Dim seq As Effect
Set seq = s.TimeLine.MainSequence.Item(animIdx)
On Error GoTo UnknownEffect
For behaviourIdx = seq.Behaviors.Count To 1 Step -1
    Dim behavior As AnimationBehavior
    Set behavior = seq.Behaviors.Item(behaviourIdx)
    If behavior.Type = msoAnimTypeSet Then
        If behavior.SetEffect.Property = msoAnimVisibility Then
            If behavior.SetEffect.To <> 0 Then
                seq.Shape.Tags.Delete AnimVisibilityTag
                seq.Shape.Tags.Add AnimVisibilityTag, "false"
            Else
                seq.Shape.Tags.Delete AnimVisibilityTag
                seq.Shape.Tags.Add AnimVisibilityTag, "true"
            End If
        End If
    End If
Next behaviourIdx
NextSequence:
On Error GoTo 0
Next animIdx
Exit Sub

UnknownEffect:
MsgBox ("Encountered an error while calculating object visibility: " + Err.Description)
Resume NextSequence
End Sub

Private Function expandAnimationsForSlide(pres As Presentation, s As Slide) As Integer
Dim numSlides As Integer
numSlides = 1

' Play the animation back to determine visibility
Do While True
' Stop when animation is over or we hit a click trigger
If s.TimeLine.MainSequence.Count <= 0 Then Exit Do
Dim fx As Effect
Set fx = s.TimeLine.MainSequence.Item(1)
If fx.Timing.TriggerType = msoAnimTriggerOnPageClick Then Exit Do

' Play the animation
PlayAnimationEffect fx
fx.Delete
Loop

' Make a copy of the slide and recurse
If s.TimeLine.MainSequence.Count > 0 Then
s.TimeLine.MainSequence.Item(1).Timing.TriggerType = msoAnimTriggerWithPrevious
Dim nextSlide As Slide
Set nextSlide = s.Duplicate.Item(1)
numSlides = 1 + expandAnimationsForSlide(pres, nextSlide)
End If

' Apply visibility
rescan = True
While rescan
rescan = False
For n = 1 To s.Shapes.Count
    If s.Shapes.Item(n).Tags.Item(AnimVisibilityTag) = "false" Then
        s.Shapes.Item(n).Delete
        rescan = True
        Exit For
    End If
Next n
Wend

' Clear all tags
For Each oShape In s.Shapes
oShape.Tags.Delete AnimVisibilityTag
Next oShape

' Remove animation (since they've been expanded now)
While s.TimeLine.MainSequence.Count > 0
s.TimeLine.MainSequence.Item(1).Delete
Wend

expandAnimationsForSlide = numSlides
End Function


Private Sub assignColor(ByRef varColor As ColorFormat, valueColor As ColorFormat)
If valueColor.Type = msoColorTypeScheme Then
varColor.SchemeColor = valueColor.SchemeColor
Else
varColor.RGB = valueColor.RGB
End If
End Sub


Private Sub PlayAnimationEffect(fx As Effect)
On Error GoTo UnknownEffect
For n = 1 To fx.Behaviors.Count
Dim behavior As AnimationBehavior
Set behavior = fx.Behaviors.Item(n)
Select Case behavior.Type
    Case msoAnimTypeSet
        ' Appear or disappear
        If behavior.SetEffect.Property = msoAnimVisibility Then
            If behavior.SetEffect.To <> 0 Then
                fx.Shape.Tags.Delete AnimVisibilityTag
                fx.Shape.Tags.Add AnimVisibilityTag, "true"
            Else
                fx.Shape.Tags.Delete AnimVisibilityTag
                fx.Shape.Tags.Add AnimVisibilityTag, "false"
            End If
        Else
            ' Log the problem
        End If
    Case msoAnimTypeColor
        ' Change color
        If fx.Shape.HasTextFrame Then
            Dim range As TextRange
            Set range = fx.Shape.TextFrame.TextRange
            assignColor range.Paragraphs(fx.Paragraph).Font.Color, behavior.ColorEffect.To
        End If


    Case Else
        ' Log the problem
End Select
Next n
Exit Sub
UnknownEffect:
MsgBox ("Encountered an error expanding animations: " + Err.Description)
Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

For those of you using LibreOffice or OpenOffice,
there is a plugin available on github that does this very well :

[ExpandAnimations](https://github.com/monperrus/ExpandAnimations)

In my experience, all of the standard appear/disappear animations are nicely split. Object movement animations also work (you get a slide with start position and one with end position of the object). I haven't had the chance to test other animation types, but that should cover about all standard needs :-)